# Why is this page wider than the display?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal website, and I've run into a problem: After using CSS and a container to center my list, the page is wider than the display causing a horizontal scrollbar. Why is this? The relevant code:

HTML:

```
<h2>My Stack:</h2>
<div class="list">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Vim</li>
    <li>Git</li>
    <li>Zsh</li>
    <li>Byobu</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7 {
    text-align: center;
}
p, div.list{
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Live copy: https://www.k7dxs.xyz/linux.php

Theoretically, the navbar should compress and the text should wrap, right? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Remove `width:100%;` from the body tag

Comment: The `margin: 0 2em 0 2em;` CSS is the problem. See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ccxognay/1/

Comment: can you please provide us with a fiddle replicating your issue?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `margin` CSS from the `body` tag:

```
body {
    // margin: 0 2em 0 2em; <-- remove this
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}
div.main {
    margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
}
```

Wrap your content in the `container-fluid` instead:

```
<div class="container-fluid main">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- the nav -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! To clarify for future readers, I'd recommend showing margins on the container-fluid.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the 2em margin on the body, to compensate for that you can use the `width: calc()`, This will set 100% width minus the `4em` body margin.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/55/

```
body {
    margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: calc(100% - 4em);
}
```

Comment: Could also set `box-sizing: border-box;` and not have to worry about the width calc.

Comment: Good idea with the calc function. I didn't know about that. The reason I'm accepting the other is because it seems like a less "hackish" way to do it.

Comment: @VirtualDXS I don't mind that you did not accept my answer, however Hynes comment below my answer would probably be the best solution, and `calc()` is not hackish it is just very precise ;)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Is that a better way than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Hynes If so, please add an answer and explain.

Comment: @VirtualDXS Answer provided

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting horizontal scrollbars is because your body is larger than the viewport. By default widths are set by "content-box". So if your `<body>` tag has the following CSS:

```
width: 100%;
margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
```

… this means the body tag will be 100% **plus** 2em margin (twice). Remember as well as that margin add to the outside of an element.

You could change the default box-sizing to `box-sizing: border-box;`. This will calculate the div's width including borders, margins, and padding.

Comment: I see. This is definitely a better solution for a non-Bootstrap page, so upvoted. The other one is still better for me because you're supposed to surround everything in a `container-fluid` in Bootstrap anyway, so I accepted the other. Thanks!

Comment: @VirtualDXS See, better then my answer :) and explained very well +1

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a left and right margin on your body, but at the same time it is 100% width so it will extend pass 100% of the window width.

Remove this line:

```
margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
```

and then it should fit 100% without the horizontal scrollbar.